# Multithreading and Global instances of classes?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

I am using mutlithreading 'first time' for a network application, my question is two related part , 
If i represent for example bunch of messages in udp with a classes (each message a class), would it be a good practice to make instances of such classes global in order to send them at different threads,  or the better approach is to use a struct having a class instance and all the socket information as a reference inside that struct (then use Pthread_create )

I reckon that in the first option , a great deal of care must be taken in order to avoid simultaneous access to data (use the pthread_mutex )

please suggest how would you approach this problem.

I really would appreciate thehelp

Thank you very much

Comment: You don't need to use threads for network programming.  Use `select()` or your platform's equivalent.  Or `libev`.

Comment: If you go the c++11 or c11 way, and your compiler supports threads, you should use that instead of pthreads.

Comment: Avoid situations where many threads have to share a single value (and thus synchronise its usage).

Comment: @JohnZwinck: `select` or similar is fine for a small number of sockets, but restricts you to a single CPU. Sadly, these days, you need concurrency if you want to use all of a computer's resources.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is , able to send a period message in the background to a client while receiving messages from that client who also sends period messages.  I figured create mutlithreads, in one threads i would send periodically the periodic messages, while doing the rest in other threads. am i reasoning correctly, i read somewhere to use Select, but i'm not sure if this the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you plan to have a listener thread that receveives messages and dispatches them to several threads that process these message concurently.

Here a possible approach would be to use a shared [queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/):

- The listner `push()` the messages it receives on the queue :
- The worker threads, if the queue is not `empty()`, take the next element to process (``` front()``and ```pop()`)
- Of course the queue shall be locked when reading or writing elements with a [mutex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/), unless you use a lokc-free queue implementation.

Only the queue needs to be shared.  You can do this with a global definition.  But on the other side, it's good practice to avoid global variables/objects whenver you can. So you'd better instantiate the queue dynamically when you create and launch your threads and pass the reference to the queueue to each of them.

With C++11 [standard threads](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/) it would look somewhat like:

```
    ... 
    std::queue<my_message_class> work_to_do;       // create queue
    std::thread t1(listener, std::ref(work_to_do));   // launch listener
    int n = max(2, std::thread::hardware_concurrency()-1);   // maximize concurency for the hardware
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        v.push_back(std::thread{ worker_function, std::ref(work_to_do) });
    }
    ...  // do something else and wait until it finishes
    t1.join();  // wait until listner finishes 
    for (auto& x :  workers) { // wait until all the worker threads finish. 
        x.join();
    }
    ...
```

where `void listener(std::queue<my_message_class>& q)` and  `void worker(std::queue<my_message_class>& q)` would be the functions to execute.

Of course, you could do similar things with pthreads.  But the standards ones have the advantage of being platform independent.